# Exception: The non-notebook version of vpython requires Python 3.5 or later

Tags: python, python-3.x, vpython

I just bought a new computer so I decided to install python. I installed the last version which is 3.10. Afterwards I decided to installed all the libraries I ussually use. One of my main projects require using a library called "vpython". It was very difficult to reinstall everything, but I managed to do it. Once i tried importing the library, this error came up:

```
Exception: The non-notebook version of vpython requires Python 3.5 or later.
vpython does work on Python 2.7 and 3.4 in the Jupyter notebook environment.
```

In the error, it clearly sais it requires Python 3.5 **or later** which I think it also includes my current version 3.10. Do I need to unintasall Python 3.10 and install an older version? There is any way to solve this without reinstalling?

Also, im not using jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by bad version checking by the creator/s of the package.

```
import platform
__p = platform.python_version()

# Delete platform now that we are done with it
del platform

__ispython3 = (__p[0] == '3')
__require_notebook = (not __ispython3) or (__p[2] < '5') # Python 2.7 or 3.4 require Jupyter notebook

if __require_notebook and (not _isnotebook):
        s = "The non-notebook version of vpython requires Python 3.5 or later."
        s += "\nvpython does work on Python 2.7 and 3.4 in the Jupyter notebook environment."
        raise Exception(s)
```

`platform.python_version()` in this case is `"3.10"` so `__p[2] < '5'` will be `True` and fail the version check.

The relevant code can be found [here](https://github.com/vpython/vpython-jupyter/blob/master/vpython/__init__.py#L20).

This should probably get a bug report if it doesn't have one already.

Ideally the check would look something like this:

```
import sys
__p = sys.version_info

# Delete sys now that we are done with it
del sys

__ispython3 = (__p.major == 3)
__require_notebook = (not __ispython3) or (__p.minor < 5) # Python 2.7 or 3.4 require Jupyter notebook

if __require_notebook and (not _isnotebook):
        s = "The non-notebook version of vpython requires Python 3.5 or later."
        s += "\nvpython does work on Python 2.7 and 3.4 in the Jupyter notebook environment."
        raise Exception(s)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So there is any way I can fix this error locally on my computer. Like I search for this init.py file and change the incorrect version check with the correct code you provided?

Comment: It should be in `lib/sitepackages/vpython/__init__.py` in your python installation directory. Just change out the first section I pasted with the second section and it should work. Disclaimer: I have not tested it at all.

Comment: No problem. I opened an issue and created a pull request so it's just up to the maintainers to approve it.